# Нужны ли кавычки? Или заменить на тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Через двести метров, зимбабвиец показал мне: «здесь».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Через двести метров зимбабвиец показал мне: здесь.**

Это БСП со значением пояснения (что именно показал). Классический вариант ― это двоеточие, но можно поставить и тире (авторский выбор).

Для постановки кавычек нет причины, это не прямая речь. Запятая также не нужна, это обычное обстоятельство.